# TLC5955 fails to drive LED's

Tags: led-driver

I am using [TLC5955](http://www.ti.com/product/TLC5955), 48 channel pwm driver from TI to drive my LED's. I have chained 4 IC's as shown driven by a CortexM4F STmicro controller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVF3pm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I believe i am sending the right data, but I have been unable to see even the smallest flicker from the LED's. I tried to feed data just into the first driver to see that it functions. I probed the SOUT of the driver, and it does show activity, which makes me believe that the Driver IC is not dead. The OUT pins of the driver however do not show any activity.

Below are the few waveforms that I captured.

[image: Start section of CONTROL]
Start section of Control Data

[image: CONTROL Data]
Full Control Data

[image: Start section of DATA]
Start section of DATA

[image: DATA]
Complete DATA

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with solving the problem...

[image]
Microcontroller

[image]
TLC5955

[image]
A part of the layout, with microcontroller on the left and the first led driver on the right(Sorry, its not the best view)

Comment: Show measued oscilligrams and actual layout, not your simulations. "I believe i am sending the right data" your job as an engineer is to find out, not believe.

Comment: That is the actual waveform taken from the circuit, but using a logic analyzer though..

Comment: That was a figure of speech, not to be taken literally :)

Comment: Show layout around the TLC5955. Vcc bypass caps? Is your logic analyzer behaves just like any digital input, you might get away using it instead an actual oscilloscope.

Comment: @winny Added the layout..

Comment: Does the TLC5955 provide a constant current sink by itself?

Comment: Yes it does... I have added a few rendered images of the pcb here..
http://shortcircuits.io/bike-pov-hardware-design.html

Comment: Neat! I can't find anything obviously wrong. Does any of your data lines require pull-up? Have you read the datasheet correctly and are you initializing the IC correctly?

Comment: I try again tomorrow, and see if i made any mistakes in the initialization.. Thanks for the help..

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: The data sheet for the LED's were wrong, and I had soldered all my 64 LED's in reverse :)